# Can php be injected, just like sql?

Tags: php

I was just wondering, whether if `php` can be injected just like the way `mysql` can be injected. I have a rough idea of how `sql injection` is done, and have successfully carried it out in development environment. So I was just wondering if php too could be injected.

Though I myself have a gut feeling that it would **not** be the case since even if tried it would be more like trying to inject a mysqli prepared statement.

And no! I am not talking about injecting `javascript` into the input I am talking about plain php-html injection through input/GET/POST . **Like stopping the current php code execution and inserting your own code in between.**

Comment: Google "is php vulnerable" and you'll see a whole bunch of links. The short answer is "yes". Here's one find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability and another https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783137/examples-of-vulnerable-php-code

Comment: PHP is just a language for serverside web programming. If the data interacting with the server/database is not sanitized, you open up the possibility of injection.

Comment: I always take my PHP intravenously, dont you? Wow feel the buzz man!

Comment: Also: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Direct_Dynamic_Code_Evaluation_%28%27Eval_Injection%27%29

Comment: if you are not using `eval()` I wouldn't worry too much

Comment: @RiggsFolly Coffee's that good huh Smokey? ;-) what're you putting in that anyway? You're not Irish.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Dude!! :D that joke just killed me .

Comment: Pretty much all scripting languages provide for dynamic code evaluation. PHP more than others (X-Ref: [Exploitable PHP functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3115559)). Variables and input values *all by themselves* do not.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783137/examples-of-vulnerable-php-code

Comment: @Fred-ii- but that is talking about SQL_injection and not the php vulnerability.

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib go through the whole page. Don't tell me you read that within 30 seconds. Mario's link talks about that also.

Comment: possible duplicate of *too broad*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this might be possible. If you use eval() or output buffering for generating your output and do not properly escape values stored in the database before you feed it to your template parser, the PHP code within might be executed.

If you use plain PHP in your templates the risk is rather high.