# can't get id with $_GET method

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I have a problem. I'm trying to get the users ID from the link.

```
localhost/projekt/php/rules.php?user=1
```

Then i save the user ID with `$ID = $_GET['user'];`

It's working, but then after i press a button where i need the ID, it says: user is undefined.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'logins');

$id = $_GET["user"];

$var = 0;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {

        $sql = "SELECT rulesaccepted FROM logins WHERE ID = '$id'";

        foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
            $sql3 = "UPDATE logins SET rulesaccepted = '1' WHERE ID = '$id'";
            $conn->query($sql3);
            header('Location: main.php');
        }   
    } else {
        $var = 1;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: add your html form code

Comment: I think when you submit your form you don't send 'user' attribute. Show your html code and it will be clear.

Comment: what's the contents of `main.php`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope that when you click button the `localhost/projekt/php/rules.php?user=1` don't fire again.
That is why it says: user is undefined

You can use `$_GET['user']` in your form  as the following

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['user'] ?>" />
```

Then you can use id when button click

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $id=$_POST['id']

        $sql = "SELECT rulesaccepted FROM logins WHERE ID = '$id'";

        foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
            $sql3 = "UPDATE logins SET rulesaccepted = '1' WHERE ID = '$id'";
            $conn->query($sql3);
            header('Location: main.php');
        }   
    } else {
        $var = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: still not working :(
Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt\php\rules.php on line 4

Comment: Have you write "<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['user'] ?>" />" in your form? If write then  execute project from  the following url "localhost/projekt/php/rules.php?user=1"

Comment: i don't have a form in the rules.php file

Comment: what about $_POST['submit']? How to do $_POST data such as $_POST['checkbox'],$_POST['submit'] without form ?

Answer (score 0):

that's because you are redirecting to `main.php` which has no `user` attribute .

so you will need to check if the `user` [isset](http://php.net/isset) .

```
if (isset($_GET["user"]) {
    $id = $_GET["user"];
}
```

#### and you must notice

because your code is highly [vulnerable to sql injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783137/examples-of-vulnerable-php-code), it's highly recommended to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

this lines : 
    $sql3 = "UPDATE logins SET rulesaccepted = '1' WHERE ID = '$id'";
    $conn->query($sql3);

would be better to be as follows:

```
$sql3 = "UPDATE logins SET rulesaccepted = '1' WHERE ID=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql3);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

**and same to your select query** :)